# Show two sets of lat/long points on Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have two sets of lat/long coordinates on a data source:

```
lat_orig    long_orig    lat_dest   long_dest    value
-12,2354    -55,2342     -5,3425    -32,3245      2
-11,2342    -44,9878     -14,3459   -54,2342      4
```

and would like to show both points on the same map on Tableau, is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, but you need to pivot your data a bit:

```
LAT  LON TYPE   VALUE
-12  -55 ORIGIN 2
-112 -45 ORIGIN 4
-5   -32 DEST   2
-14  -54 DEST   4
```

and then if you want to draw lines between your places you need to add a path ID:

```
LAT      LON        TYPE    VALUE   PATH
-12.2354 -55.2342   ORIGIN  2       2-2
-5.3425  -32.3245   DEST    2       2-2
-112.342 -44.9878   ORIGIN  4       4-4
-14.3459 -54.2342   DEST    4       4-4
```

[image]

Here is a great tutorial: http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/using-path-shelf-pattern-analysis

**UPDATE**:
To get labels you can do a dual axis and overlay the labels:
[image]

Comment: The path id is based on the value column?

Comment: Basically, for each data pair, you need to create a unique key that identifies them as a pair. I don't really know your data, but I made a guess. See step 2 of the tutorial in the link above for a better example.

Comment: Thanks, going through the tutorial.

Comment: It worked, after pivoting my data in Python. I need to show the labels, but if I use the column that I have with the label, the repeated values will be shown several times. Is there a way around it?

Comment: In my example you can use "path" for the label. You can use "path ID" in the example from the tutorial. Try downloading the workbook and trying it: http://kbcdn.tableausoftware.com/workbooks/using-path-shelf-pattern-analysis-example.twbx

Comment: Thanks. I followed the workbook. The problem is that some points are both origin and destination for different routes, so it shows twice on the map, and the Path_ID from the example is just a number, what I need is to show the City Column.